# Remove backup on Windows PC iTunes

Tags: itunes, windows, backup, ipad

Now that iCloud is available, I don't need to backup my iPad to my Windows PC. Is it possible to remove backups from my PC or do I have to uninstall iTunes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, it certainly is!

in Windows XP, the location is

```
C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup
```

in Windows Vista, Windows 7:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup
```

Comment: I'll just delete the files inside the folder and iTunes won't protest?

Comment: That's correct. But be aware... You WON'T be able to use a back-up. So I recommend you don't delete the latter back-up. Just in case :)